# Checking if email address already exists in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, error-handling, if-statement

I'm trying to error handle a registration aspx/c# page on my application and want to run a check whether the email address that a user has tried to register already exists as the email address is used as a primary key in my database.

I have tried IF NOT EXISTS/IF EXISTS but these dont give the desired effect so was wondering if there was another way around it?

Look forward to your reply,

Scott

Comment: please expand upon "don't give the required effect".

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(*) from users where email = @email

(int)executescalar > 0 == dupe
```

Comment: And if that doesn't work you might want to post a screenshot of your schema and the database engine you are using

Answer (score 0):

First answer certainly works, but a slightly more performant example would be:

```
select top 1 null from users where email = @email
```

on large or poorly-indexed tables.